# Multiple processes for my app on Android

Tags: android, memory-management, service, memory-leaks, process

I have observed that there are multiple processes of my app (with same app name and same package name) in the Settings > Developer options > Process Stats.(like this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/01/process-stats-understanding-how-your.html)
I have not defined multiple processes anywhere in my project no `<android:process= : name>` in manifest..It has few activities and a service.

[image]

It would be great if anyone help me to understand ..if this behaviour is correct..
As my app is already consuming high memory.

Comment: If your manifest, or the manifest of any library that you use, has a component with the `android:process` attribute, and that component runs, it will run in a different process than the main one for your app. So, this behavior can be correct.

Comment: ... or you have `SameAppName(diff.packages.names)` `SameAppName(diff.packages.names.debug)` installed at the same time

Comment: Same App name ,SAme Package name in both cases.. In my manifest no defined process

Comment: @Selvin no I have installed only one apk